# Use JS map/reduce to merge array of objects instead of forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to learn better use of JS functions and I have a feeling what I'm after can be done using reduce or map or both, but I simply cannot find examples of this particular scenario:

I have an array of objects, eg:

```
const data =  [
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 0,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 100,
        "favorites": 0
    },
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 2,
        "categories": 1,
        "total": 400,
        "favorites": 1
    },
    {
        "member": "222222",
        "offers": 1,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 50,
        "favorites": 5
    }
]
```

The goal is to reduce to an array that merges all the key values into ONE array for each member, ie:

```
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 2,
        "categories": 1,
        "total": 500,
        "favorites": 1
    },
    {
        "member": "222222",
        "offers": 1,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 50,
        "favorites": 5
    },
```

Therefore, there were two entries for member 111111, they have been merged and all the other values summed into a single array.

Honestly, everything I've tried is a mess, so apart from using the boring for loops or adding code here that is clearly rubbish, I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```js
const data =  [
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 0,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 100,
        "favorites": 0
    },
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 2,
        "categories": 1,
        "total": 400,
        "favorites": 1
    },
    {
        "member": "222222",
        "offers": 1,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 50,
        "favorites": 5
    }
]


let result = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.member] = a[b.member] || {member : b.member};
  for(let property of Object.keys(b)){
    if(property == 'member') continue;
    a[b.member][property] = a[b.member][property] || 0;
    a[b.member][property] += b[property];
  }
  return a;
}, {});

result = Object.keys(result).map(e => result[e]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that is beautiful JS, exactly what I was after

Comment: not to push my luck - but if there's any chance u could explain some of the lines, I would appreciate it - I'm really trying to improve my real understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

Heres another example with just a reduce and indexOf

```js
const data =  [
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 0,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 100,
        "favorites": 0
    },
    {
        "member": "111111",
        "offers": 2,
        "categories": 1,
        "total": 400,
        "favorites": 1
    },
    {
        "member": "222222",
        "offers": 1,
        "categories": 0,
        "total": 50,
        "favorites": 5
    }
]

const merge = (target, props) => {
  for(p in props){
    if(p !== 'member') {
      target[p] += props[p]
    }
  }
  return target
}

const a = data.reduce((res, d) => {
  const idx = res.findIndex(r => r.member === d.member)
  if (idx >= 0) {
    const newRes = merge(res[idx], {...d})
    res.splice(res[idx], 1, newRes)
  } else {
    res.push(d)
  }
  return res
}, [])

console.log(a)
```